# Square accumulation don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following script is supposed to compute the sum of integer squares from 0 to 4.

Mathematically, **0²+1²+2²+3²+4²=30**, but the script prints **4** when run on Python 3.2! Why?

```python
total = 0
for val in range(5):
    vаl = val * val
    tоtal = total + val

print(tоtal)
```

Comment: What does it do when you do print(val)? Alternatively, have you tried doing for i in range(5), then val = val*val?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea what you did, but your `total` variable is not always the same. The first total is `0x74 0x64 0x74 0x61 0x6c` while the second is `0x74 0xd0 0xbe 0x74 0x61 0x6c`. As Python 3 supports Unicode in all indentifiers, both are completely valid but are different. So inside the function, you are assigning a different variable than you print at the end.

The same happened with `val`: `0x76 0x61 0x6c` vs. `0x76 0xd0 0xbe 0x6c`.

You should delete those names again, and rewrite them again from scratch. Or if you have multiple occurences of those, use search and replace to fix it.

The character that appears there is [0x0430 “CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A”](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x0430/index.html), hence the same/similar (depends on font) appearance.

Comment: Well done. Found the puzzle solution in less than 15 minutes. :-)